# Routing a subdomain in CakePHP with HTML-Helper

Tags: php, cakephp, mobile, cakephp-1.3, html-helper

I have a mobile page running on a subdomain "m.mydomain.com". This is all working fine, but I would like to remove the controller in the URL when using the subdomain.

```
m.mydomain.com/mobiles/tips
```

should become

```
m.mydomain.com/tips
```

by using the HTML-Helper.

At the moment a link looks like that:

```
$html->link('MyLink', array('controller' => 'mobiles', 'action'=> 'tips'));
```

I tried several possible solutions with the routes and also some hacks in the bootstrap but it did not work out for me.

In the CakeBakery I found [this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Mum_Chamber/2008/02/04/subdomaining-with-cake) but that does not solve my issue.

Does anyone have an idea for this issue?

Comment: Whenever you get to look at my answer, please comment if it's not working, so we can work towards a definitive answer. This question may help a lot of other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gathering code from the page you mentioned:

**Constraint**: you cannot have a controller called `tips` or `foo` in this setup

In `/config/routes.php`:

```
$subdomain = substr( env("HTTP_HOST"), 0, strpos(env("HTTP_HOST"), ".") );

if( strlen($subdomain)>0 && $subdomain != "m" ) { 
    Router::connect('/tips',array('controller'=>'mobiles','action'=>'tips'));
    Router::connect('/foo', array('controller'=>'mobiles','action'=>'foo'));
    Configure::write('Site.type', 'mobile');
}

/* The following is available via default routes '/{:controller}/{:action}'*/
// Router::connect('/mobiles/tips', 
//                  array('controller' => 'mobiles', 'action'=>'tips'));
// Router::connect('/mobiles/foo',  
//                  array('controller' => 'mobiles', 'action'=>'foo'));
```

In your Controller action:

```
$site_is_mobile = Configure::read('Site.type') ?: '';
```

Then in your view:

```
<?php

if ( $site_is_mobile ) {
    // $html will take care of the 'm.example.com' part
    $html->link('Cool Tips', '/tips');
    $html->link('Hot Foo', '/foo');
} else {
    // $html will just output 'www.example.com' in this case
    $html->link('Cool Tips', '/mobiles/tips');
    $html->link('Hot Foo', '/mobiles/foo');
}

?>
```

This will allow you to output the right links in your views (in a bit I'll show you how to write even less code) but the `$html` helper will not be able -- by no amount of magic -- to use controller-action routes to another domain. Be aware that `m.example.com` and `www.example.com` are different domains as far as the `$html` helper is concerned.

Now, if you want you can do the following in your controller to take some logic off your view:

```
<?php

$site_is_mobile = Configure::read('Site.type') ?: '';

if ( $site_is_mobile !== '' ) {
    $tips_url = '/tips';
    $foo_url  = '/foo';
} else {
    $tips_url = '/mobile/tips';
    $foo_url  = '/mobile/foo';
}

// make "urls" available to the View
$this->set($tips_url);
$this->set($foo_url);

?>
```

And in your view you don't need to worry about checking whether the site is being accessed via `m.example.com/tips` or `www.example.com/mobile/tips`:

```
<?php echo $html->link("Get some kewl tips", $tips_url); ?>
```

For more advanced routing in CakePHP-1.3 refer to [Mark Story's article on custom `Route classes`](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp)

Let us know ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help Oerd! This works, but I was looking for something which would work both ways: www.mydomain.com/mobiles/tips and m.mydomain.com/tips. Is this possible with the html helper?

Comment: @chris if you have a mobiles controller, it would work right out of the box, provided `your_controller` is called in reality `mobiles_controller.php`

Comment: @chris, I'm updating the answer

Comment: @Oerd thanks again. So I need to have the If/Else statement? Theres is no way that the routes in combination with the html helper do the magic for me in order to just use this: $html->link('MyLink', array('controller' => 'mobiles', 'action'=> 'tips'));

Comment: @Oerd Even this is not what I was looking for, I will go for this solution, since I don't have other/better ideas :-) Thanks again! I thought there might be a solution with the routes.php, since here is the magic where e.g. `Router::connect('/test', array('controller' => 'mobiles', 'action' => 'index'));` and `$html->link('MyLink', array('controller' => 'mobiles', 'action'=> 'index'));` will create this link `/test` and not `/mobiles`. So I thought I could remove the `/mobiles` somehow using the routes... But anyway, I will go for your proposal now :-)

Comment: @chris if Mark Story's article on custom route classes doesn't help you any further, nothing will (check last line of my answer)